# merge sort in python IndexError

Tags: python, mergesort, index-error

In my merge sort implementation using python, run time an error occurred as

> `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Here is the code:

```
#merge
def merge(array, low, mid, high):
   n1 = mid - low + 1
   n2 = high - mid
   ll = [] * n1
   rr = [] * n2
   for i in range(n1):
      ll[i] = array[low + i]
   for j in range(n2):
      rr[j] = array[mid + 1 + j]

   (i, j) = (0, 0)
   k = low

   while i < n1 and j < n2:
      if ll[i] <= rr[j]:
         array[k] = ll[i]
         i = i + 1
      else:
         array[k] = rr[j]
         j = j + 1
   k = k + 1
   #for remaining members of the lists
   while i < n1:
      array[k] = ll[i]
      i = i + 1
      k = k + 1                

   while i < n2:
      array[k] = rr[j]
      j = j + 1
      k = k + 1
```

method for merge sort

```
def mergesort(array, low, high):
   if low < high:
      mid = low + (high - low) // 2

      #recurrence
      mergesort(array, low, mid)
      mergesort(array, mid + 1, high)
      merge(array, low, mid, high)
```

driver

```
array = [ 74, 32, 89, 55, 21, 64 ]
mergesort(array, 0, len(array))
```

while running the code am getting an error that says `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message.

Comment: @DYZ the full error message is  >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mergesort.py", line 48, in <module>
    mergesort(list , 0 , len(list))         
  File "mergesort.py", line 43, in mergesort
    mergesort(array , low , mid)
  File "mergesort.py", line 43, in mergesort
    mergesort(array , low , mid)
  File "mergesort.py", line 45, in mergesort
    merge(array , low , mid , high)
  File "mergesort.py", line 12, in merge
    ll[i] = array[ low + i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Now that you know where is the problem, you should do debugging. For instance, start by print `array , low , mid , high`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the length of the array as the second argument to `merge`, but the `merge` function seems to expect the index of the last element in the range to be sorted.

This API is classic but poorly chosen as you cannot specify an empty range and it is less regular, requiring some extra adjustments (`+ 1` and `- 1` on subarray sizes etc.). You should modify the code so `high` is the index of the first element **after** the range to be sorted.

There are other problems in the `merge` function:

- the computation for the subarray sizes is incorrect
- you increment `k` outside the `while` loop: `k = k + 1` should be incremented in level deeper.
- the last loop should use `j` instead of `i` as the index.
- this implementation uses *recursion*, not *recurrence*

Here is a modified version:

```py
def merge(array, low, mid, high):
   n1 = mid - low
   n2 = high - mid
   ll = [] * n1
   rr = [] * n2
   for i in range(n1):
      ll[i] = array[low + i]
   for j in range(n2):
      rr[j] = array[mid + j]

   i = 0
   j = 0
   k = low

   while i < n1 and j < n2:
      if ll[i] <= rr[j]:
         array[k] = ll[i]
         i = i + 1
      else:
         array[k] = rr[j]
         j = j + 1
      k = k + 1

   #copy the remaining members of the lists
   while i < n1:
      array[k] = ll[i]
      i = i + 1
      k = k + 1                

   while j < n2:
      array[k] = rr[j]
      j = j + 1
      k = k + 1  

def mergesort(array, low, high):
   if high - low > 1:
      mid = low + (high - low) // 2

      #recursion
      mergesort(array, low, mid)
      mergesort(array, mid, high)
      merge(array, low, mid, high)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code, fixed version looks like this (fixed lines are commented):

**merge**

```
def merge(array, low, mid, high):
    n1 = mid - low + 1
    n2 = high - mid
    ll = [0] * n1  # here
    rr = [0] * n2  # here

    for i in range(n1):
        ll[i] = array[low + i]
    for j in range(n2):
        rr[j] = array[mid + 1 + j]

    i, j = 0, 0
    k = low

    while i < n1 and j < n2 :
        if ll[i] <= rr[j]:
           array[k] = ll[i]
           i += 1
        else:
           array[k] = rr[j]
           j += 1
        k += 1
    while i < n1:
       array[k] = ll[i]
       i += 1
       k += 1

    while j < n2:  # here
      array[k] = rr[j]
      j += 1
      k += 1
```

**mergesort**

```
def mergesort(array, low, high):
   if low < high:
        mid = (low + (high - 1)) // 2  # here

        mergesort(array, low, mid)
        mergesort(array, mid + 1, high)
        merge(array, low, mid, high)
```

and final function call:

```
array = [74 , 32 , 89 , 55 , 21 , 64]
mergesort(array , 0 , len(array) - 1)  # here
```